# Which parameters goes in Chrome to emulate iPhone X?

Tags: google-chrome

[image: chrome tools screenshot]

I tried with the above settings but I'm getting nowhere. Thanks.

Comment: I would assume you would just enter the resolution of the iPhone X and assigned it the appropriate user agent string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the settings for emulate iPhone X on the Chrome debugger.

- iPhone X
- 375 x 812 @ 3
- Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 11_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/604.1.34 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0 Mobile/15A5341f Safari/604.1

The user-agent string is for Safari in iOS 11

:)